# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier. Remix IDE

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am getting the declaration error and I am not sure why.  The error is in this line
"    function getSpaceAvailability(uint _space) view  returns(bool) {
return spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable;
}"

Here is the affected code -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

/// @title This contract will create an Air BNB type system 
/// @notice Development Purposes Only!
/// @dev Feel free to contribute or fix bugs or errors
/// @custom:experimental This is an experimental contract

/**
* @title Setup the cUSD token contract interface
*/
interface CUSDToken {
  function approve(address, uint256) external returns (bool);
  function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address, address, uint256) external returns (bool);
}

contract celoBNB {
    // ***************
    // DEFINITIONS
    // ***************
    
    // Define the addresses as 'payable' so we can send funds
    address payable lessorAddress;
    address payable leaseeAddress;

    // We define the home or apartment as a struct
    // We need to store the price, the Celo address of the current occupant
    // and if the space is available.
    struct space {
        uint256 pricecUSD;
        address currentOccupant;
        bool spaceIsAvailable;
        }
    
    // For testing purposes we will assume the owner has 8 spaces to rent.
    // In production we would make this flexible
    // and allow the owner to add and remove spaces as desired
    space[8] spaceDB;
    
      /// @notice cUSD default contract address: 0x874069Fa1Eb16D44d622F2e0Ca25eeA172369bC1
    address internal cUsdTokenAddress;
    
    // We'll use a modifier to limit who can call to the owner
    modifier ownerOnly() {
        require(msg.sender == lessorAddress);
        _;
        }
    
        // We will run this once only when the contract is created
    constructor() public {
        
        // This stores the address that creates the contract as 'lessorAddress'
        lessorAddress = msg.sender;
        
        // Let's fill the array with test data
        // (all spaces available, even # spaces cost 1 cUSD, odd #s cost 2 cUSD)
        // We don't have to use but this gives us some testing data
        for (uint i=0; i<8; i++) {
            spaceDB[i].spaceIsAvailable = true;
            }
    }


    // ***************
    // GETTERS
    // ***************
    
    // This getter tells us if a space is available or not
    function getSpaceAvailability(uint _space) public view  returns(bool) {
        return spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable;
    }

    // This getter tells us the price of space
    function getPriceOfSpace(uint _space) public view  returns(uint256) {
        return spaceDB[_space].pricecUSD;
    }

    // This getter tells us who's renting the space at the moment
    function getCurrentOccupant(uint _space) public view  returns(address) {
        return spaceDB[_space].currentOccupant;
    }

    // ***************
    // SETTERS
    // ***************

    // This function sets the availability of a space
    
    function setSpaceAvailability(uint8 _space, bool _newAvailability) lessorOnly public {
        spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable = _newAvailability;
        // if the space is to be set as "available", let's remove the current occupant
        // There is no 'null' in Solidity, and an address can't be set to 0 (type mismatch)
        // So we need to use address(0)
        if (_newAvailability) {
            spaceDB[_space].currentOccupant = address(0);
        }
    }
    
    // This function sets the price of the space
    // Can only be called by the lessor
    function setPriceOfSpace(uint8 _space, uint256 _priceInWei) lessorOnly public {
        spaceDB[_space].pricecUSD = _pricecUSD; 
    }
    
    // This function handles the renting
    function rentASpace(uint8 _space) public payable returns(uint256) {

        // Look, a tenant!
        leaseeAddress = msg.sender;

        // Let's check if the tenant is sending the right amount
        // The modulo operator will be true if the amount is zero,
        // so we have to use &&
        if (msg.value % spaceDB[_space].pricecUSD == 0 && msg.value > 0 && spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable == true) {

            // We calculate how many days the tenant has just paid for
            uint256 numberOfNightsPaid = msg.value / spaceDB[_space].pricecUSD;

            // Set the availability to false
            spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable = false;

            // Set the tenant address in spaceDB
            spaceDB[_space].currentOccupant = leaseeAddress;

            // Send the rent to the owner
            lessorAddress.transfer(msg.value);

            // The function returns the number of days paid
            // You can use this info on the frontend
            return numberOfNightsPaid;
        
        // What is the tenant sent the wrong amount?
        // Well we send it back
        } else {
            
            // we send back the funds (minus gas)
            leaseeAddress.transfer(msg.value);
            
            // we return 0 days;
            return 0;
        }
        
    }   
}`
```

Answer (score 2):

In line 91 you are calling a modifier which is not declared!

```
function setSpaceAvailability(uint8 _space, bool _newAvailability) lessorOnly public {...}
```

Declare a modifier named `lesserOnly`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `}` before the getters

```
            }
    }
}  // <<<<<------ Move to the end

    // ***************
    // GETTERS
    // ***************
    
    // This getter tells us if a space is available or not
    function
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch but now I am getting an error "DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique." at this line -     `function setSpaceAvailability(uint8 _space, bool _newAvailability) lessorOnly public {
        spaceDB[_space].spaceIsAvailable = _newAvailability;
        if (_newAvailability) {
            spaceDB[_space].currentOccupant = address(0);
        }
    }`

Comment: @ShawnMichael That function isn't in the code you posted so I can't say for sure, but the idea is that you have to move the `}` after all the functions.

Comment: I have updated original post with full code.

Comment: I want to thank you so much @Ismael. You have been a great help